# WPF Grid - align it's children automatically

Tags: wpf, grid

There is some way, a property like VerticalContentAlignment for aligning grid children or do I have to do it manually one by one?

Answer (score 4):

If most of the grid's children are of the same type you can use styles, for example putting this at the start of the grid will align all text boxes

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
 .
 .
 .
```

If you have only a few types of controls inside the grid this is very useful.

Comment: hm - could i also target something more down the hierarchy like `frameworkelement` or something to apply it to all controls?

Answer (score 2):

If TextAlignment works for you instead of HorizontalAlignment, it can be made even simpler:

```
<Grid TextBlock.TextAlignment="Right">
    <TextBox ....
....
```